# How to set tags onclick in custom javascript object?

Tags: javascript, html, function, javascript-objects

I get confused about javascript object referring.
if I have a tag like this:

```
<button id='myButton'>Hello</button>
```

and I make a custom class in javascript:

```
function myClass(){
    this.myButton= document.getElementById('myButton');

    this.myButton.addEventListener("click",function(){
        alert(this.myButton.innerHTML);
    });
}
```

what I expect from this function is, it will shows alert popup with "Hello" text, but what I got is:

```
TypeError: this.myButton is undefined
```

Then, I try doing to change the function to:

```
function myClass(){
    this.myButton= document.getElementById('myButton');

    this.myButton.addEventListener("click",function(){
        alert(this.myButton);
    });
}
```

And what i got is an alert popup that says "undefined". Any idea to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
function myClass(){
  this.myButton= document.getElementById('myButton');
  var self = this;

  this.myButton.addEventListener("click",function(){
    alert(self.myButton);
  });
}
```

because `this` for the inline function you declared refers to `window` object.

Comment: It works. I don't know about it before. Thanks.